# How long does Ubuntu take to install? (on supermicro server)

Tags: server, software-installation

I booted ubuntu 20.04 LTS from a usb to supermicro server.
When it asked me about partitioning nothing came up so I just clicked on continue anyway.

I have been installing for about 45 mins and the install bar is still white.

last message from installing " Ubuntu systemdd[1]: package kit.service: Succeeded."

any advice?

Answer (score 0):

> When it asked me about partitioning nothing came up so I just clicked on continue anyway.

is not correct. There should always be a partition and you have to assign at least a label `/` to a partition.

This is either a bug and needs to be reported, some hardware failure, or you might need to provide a driver to have it recognize the hard drive.

- If you use SATA make sure to set it to AHCI in BIOS.

Comment: I tried to add but I can't add any thing 
device

Comment: @ghaida Please read again the last sentence and do accordingly.